# Use datejs to convert 12 hour time string to 24 hour time string

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, time, datejs

For example, if I had a string like `4:15 PM` how can I convert it to `16:15` using [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)?

`Date.parse("4:15 PM").toString("hh:mm")` returns 4:15.

Comment: Try using `"HH:mm"`

Comment: @nickzoum thank you, that worked!

Comment: Docs for the format specifiers: https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/wiki/Format-Specifiers#custom-date-and-time-format-specifiers

Comment: Thanks! That will help a lot.